# Try...catch statements exercise in Java

Tags: java, try-catch, illegalargumentexception

Java newbie here and I'm doing an exercise trying to catch thrown exceptions by using as few try...catch statements as possible. When  I compiled the code, I received `IllegalArgumentException` errors and wasn't sure how to fix this by using the try...catch statements.

I've watched tutorials, looked at other examples but since this is a new concept for me, I'm still unsure how to use the try...catch for this particular exercise.

```
public class Main extends Object {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    tryGetMax();
    tryRemove();

private static final void tryGetMax() {
    int max = 0;
    max = FunMethods.getMax((Integer[])null);
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[50];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new Integer(rand.nextInt(500));
    }
    numbers[32] = null;
    max = FunMethods.getMax(numbers);
    numbers[32] = new Integer(rand.nextInt(500));
    max = FunMethods.getMax(numbers);
}
```

The second part of the exercise:

```
private static final void tryRemove() {
    FunMethods.remove(null, 2);
    Object[] someObjects = new Object[12];
    someObjects[0] = "a string!";
    someObjects[1] = new Integer(32);
    someObjects[2] = new Float(42.5f);
    someObjects[3] = "another string";
    for (int i = 4; i < someObjects.length; i++) {
        someObjects[i] = String.valueOf(i);
    }
    FunMethods.remove(someObjects, 12);
    someObjects = FunMethods.remove(someObjects, 3);
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you've even attempted to add a try/catch statement. Did you read the documentation or look at any examples? What specifically didn't you understand?

Comment: You're right, I haven't yet. This is my confusion in terms of what lines to add the try/catch statements to make this compile correctly.

Comment: SO isn't for "teach me how to do basic stuff", sorry

Comment: Everyone started somewhere, including you. I'm just trying to understand how to incorporate it into this exercise.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but SO isn't the place to ask these kind of questions

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to that. I'm only a month into learning Java and figured this would be a good place to ask, with a lot of knowledgeable people.

Comment: "When I compiled the code, I received `IllegalArgumentException`" You received an `IllegalArgumentException` at **compile** time or **runtime**?  Your statement reads as compile time, but an `IllegalArgumentException` is typically encountered at runtime.

Comment: Hi @MJW. Welcome to SO. I offer a few words of advice. I have observed a significant correlation among down-voted questions and proclamations along the lines of "I watched the tutorials." I believe these videos are doing a disservice to the aspiring student in that they offer a false sense of understanding to the viewer. Their primary objective is garnering advertisement impressions rather than teaching. I heartily suggest the venerable Java Trail tutorials: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java. There is no short-cut to mastery. Follow the trail and you will be rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  //Code that can potentially throw an exception
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
  //Code to run if exception is throw
}
```

The exception is assigned to the variable `e` which has certain methods that could be called.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what try and catch do but I'm unsure what lines of this exercise would require the try/catch statement.

Comment: @MJW You need to find which methods that you consume or use can throw that exception. Go through the javadocs of the API you used. I am guessing its the Random class methods

Comment: I forgot that part, it's the exceptions thrown by the FunMethods class.

Answer (score 0):

ok, right under the `public static void main(String[] args) {` you should have `try {`. Then, at the end of the main method, you should have `} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {`. And under that, you should have your code for catching that exception, and `}`.

Now this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    tryGetMax();
    tryRemove();
```

Looks like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        tryGetMax();
        tryRemove();
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //this code runs if e is thrown
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. if this worked, hit the checkmark right under the vote arrows to mark that this was correct or it worked.